# Is that any way to create boost xml request to string with carriage return string added in that?

Tags: xml, boost

Expected XML output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
      <Name>XYZ</Name>
</Data>
```

Without xml_writer_settings function I am able to get below xml output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data><Name>XYZ</Name></Data>
```

With xml_writer_settings I am able to get the expected xml output but I need write down it into file and then I am converting it into string

```
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    pt.put(Data.Name, method_name);
    boost::property_tree::xml_writer_settings<char> settings('\t', 1);
    write_xml("Data.xml", pt, std::locale(), settings);
```

Is that any other way I can get xml data directly from ptree to string with carriage return strings added in that?

Comment: http://boostdoesnothaveanxmllibrary.com I'm buying the domain today. I'm getting rich off the clicks

Answer (score 1):

Just write to `std::ostringstream` instead of a file.

```
std::string xml;
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    write_xml(oss, pt, boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>(' ', 4));
    xml = oss.str();
}
```